# post gzip compressed json to jersey service

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

Jersey webmethod receives json and return json, i created a client to post the json with gzip encoding, i have no idea it is the right way to encode the the json to post, i want to confirm the request body is really compressed or not?

This is the jersey webmethod

```
 @POST
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Path("/getgzip")
 public RPGZIP postDocument(RGZIP gzip){         
     RPGZIP _response = new RPGZIP();
     _response.rpid = gzip.docid;
     _response.rpdata = gzip.docdata; 
     return _response;
 }
```

This is the client class to consume jersey

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.gzip.RGZIP;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.GZipEncoder;
public class rclient {
public static void main(String[] args){
     String REST_URI   = 
    "http://localhost:8084/TestGZip/webresources/gzip/getgzip";  
     Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
     client.register(GZipEncoder.class);
     RGZIP rzip = new RGZIP();
     rzip.docid = 1234;
     rzip.docdata = "Working..";         
     Response r =   
          client.target(REST_URI).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .post(Entity.entity(rzip, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
     System.out.println(r.readEntity(String.class));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To know that your request is compressed, there must be a request header like `Content-Encoding: gzip` sent to server for server to know that they have to decompress the payload

What you did is correct in your code.

Comment: My colleague tried to post the compressed json to the jersey method and he getting socket error? and he telling me i should add and register gzip ReaderInterceptor to consume compressed request?

Comment: i have checked the header of the request from the netbeans and the above code is not setting the content-encoding. how to set the content encoding?

Comment: Because you are overriding it in creating entity. Change the code to 
`client.target(REST_URI).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .post(Entity.entity(rzip,new Variant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE,"en","gzip")));` and you will see Content-Encoding.


But what is your ask? You are shifting from client side encoding to server side encoding to interceptors? Are u not able to send gzip encoded payload _from client_ or are u not able to _Consume_ gzip encoded payload in sever?

Comment: I am getting " HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request "  after updated the code

Comment: no error at server side. should i add reader interceptor class to receive compressed json?

Comment: this code set and content-encoding and also set the content language, any option to set the content encoding alone?

Comment: Pass language as null. Interceptor here, IMO is over doing

Comment: Response r =   client.target(REST_URI).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .post(Entity.entity(rzip, new Variant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE,"","gzip")));  --- This code set the content-encoding : gzip, my question is can web method  receive the compressed body with out Interceptor? is this code really compress the request body?